# Why do I get 0% in all cases as a result in this program?

Tags: c++

I've created this test-score program on Code::Blocks to calculate the percentage of students' tests based on the maximum reachable points and the number of points they reached on a test, but I get in all cases 0% as a result and I'm not sure why.

Can someone help me with an explanation?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])

{
  //enter the maximum reachable score
  int maxscore;
  cout << "Enter the highest possible score: ";
  cin >> maxscore;

  //enter the reached score
  int score;
  cout << "Enter your score: ";
  cin >> score;

  //calculate percentage
  //what's wrong here with the percentage calculation?
  int percentage;
  percentage =  (score/maxscore)*100 ;

  //output the results (followed by a NewLine)
  cout << "Your result is: ";
  cout << percentage <<"%"<< endl;

  //wait until user is ready before terminating the program to allow the user 
  //to see the program results
  cout << "Pres Enter to continue..."<<endl;
  cin.ignore(10, '\n');
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: keyword: integer arithmetic, `score/maxscore` does not produce the result you are expecting

Comment: @VTT then how would it work?

Comment: By changing int percentage to float percentage

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your problem is using of an integer as percentage. Use a Float for decimal places Support. Here is an Example of your Code with a Float:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])

{
  //enter the maximum reachable score
  int maxscore;
  cout << "Enter the highest possible score: ";
  cin >> maxscore;

  //enter the reached score
  int score;
  cout << "Enter your score: ";
  cin >> score;

  //calculate percentage
  //what's wrong here with the percentage calculation?
  float percentage;
  percentage =  (score/maxscore)*100 ;

  //output the results (followed by a NewLine)
  cout << "Your result is: ";
  cout << (int) (percentage+0.5) <<"%"<< endl; // fast the Float to int for Zero decimal and add 0.5 befördert fast for rounding.

  //wait until user is ready before terminating the program to allow the user 
  //to see the program results
  cout << "Pres Enter to continue..."<<endl;
  cin.ignore(10, '\n');
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo: Float->float.  I'd change it myself, but I don't want to squash things if you are mid-edit.

Comment: This answer is wrong anyway because it will still calculate percents using the same integer arithmetic expression and producing 0.0f...

Comment: Hint: Float `score` first.

Comment: There is no need to use `float` anywhere unless someone wants floating point percent value.

Comment: @VTT There is if you don't want this thing to have some egregious rounding errors.

Comment: @tadman Floating point numbers don't completely prevent rounding errors, in this case reporting an integer percent value seems to be perfectly fine.

Comment: @VTT They don't prevent rounding errors, you will always have those, but in this particular case it will minimize them. There's no reason to do it purely int here, performance will not be a problem. `float` provides the most accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
percentage =  (score/maxscore)*100 ;
```

into

```
percentage = (score*100)/maxscore ;
```

because `score/maxscore` is threated as integer and so "floor()ed" to 0 and when multiplied by 100 it could only be a multiple of 100.